# Keep existing markup in Vue's <div id="app" />

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have installed Vue using the latest CLI in to an existing .net mvc projects. My goal is to add components while keeping the existing pages intact.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
<div id="app">
    <MyNewVueComponent></MyNewVueComponent> <!-- insert my vue compoents -->        
    <p>@Model.someText</p> <!-- keep original .net mvc view content -->
</div>
```

In my main.js:

```
new Vue({}).$mount('#app')
```

This just generates a blank page at the moment.

Comment: Why not just put it outside `#app`?

Comment: `#app` serves as the application's home - you are not supposed to have anything inside it that needs preservation. Also, your Vue application can only have one root element.

Comment: @ceejayoz Because I want to integrate the components in my existing razor views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

along with `runtimeCompiler: true` in vue.config.js did the trick.